# How does this optical illusion work?

Tags: optics, biophysics

Can someone explain this? Or maybe it's not physical, but cognitive phenomenon?

[image]

Comment: http://www.michaelbach.de/ot/fcs-mosaic/index.html

Comment: To see the effect all you need to do is view the picture from further away.  The greatest change is found by first viewing the picture very close to and then moving away from it.

Answer (score 6):

It's *not* a picture of a smiling girl, It's an image blended from two pictures.  One is a *low-pass-filtered* picture of a smiling girl, and the other is a *high-pass filtered* picture of somebody (maybe the same model?) making a pouty face.

With eyes wide open, your brain picks up on the details in the high-pass image, but when you squint and look through your eyelashes, you effectively apply a low-pass filter to everything you see.  That makes the high-pass details invisible, but only makes the low-pass image a little more low-pass filtered than it already was.

You only see the low-pass filtered version when you are squinting, and that is about what your brain *expects* to see when you are squinting, and your brain says, "Ah Hah! I am looking at an image of a smiling girl through my clenched eyelashes."

Comment: Can you slightly elaborate about what are those filters and how squinting is a low pass filter? I generally like your answer, but I am not good at this stuff.