# What's so strange with this picture? Which optical phenomenon is working here?

Tags: optics

[image]

Here is the picture I am talking about. I found it on Facebook. I have seen cards in my childhood which used to show different images when tilted at different angles but this image seems strange.

Can anyone explain me which phenomenon is working here?

Edit: one more thing I found is that the smiling girl appear while looking at the image from some distance too!

Comment: Hint : The dark patches (specially above the lips) just across the white patches. They are in start contrast.

Comment: Duplicate https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/326433/104696

Comment: The "smiling girl" is Eva Longoria, right?

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be similar to the effect shown in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=41&v=tB5-JahAXfc).

The general idea is that one takes two different images, and superimposes the fine details of the one over the broader form of the other.  At close range, we resolve the first image, but far away (or apparently with half-closed eyes) we tend to see the second.

Comment: Indeed matter of focus.   I have reading glasses and if I remove them she is smiling nevertheless.